# error opening executable file on ssh - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to run tor on Ubuntu with terminal (using SSH). Whenever I am trying to open the executable file I am getting this error:

```
./tor: error while loading shared libraries: libevent-2.1.so.7:
 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to re-install the packages and nothing going well, also tried to link the library and that also did nothing. Whenever I am trying to create another executable file it runs okay, the problem is only with this tor file.

Further details:

```
$ ldd ./tor | grep libevent
libevent-2.1.so.7 => not found
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libevent*
No such file or directory
```

Can anyone guide me on how to solve it? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The obvious question would be: Is there a `libevent-2.1.so.7` in your system?

Comment: i should i have
i wrote sudo apt-get install libevent-dev and it says that it already installed
@kaylum

Comment: "should"? Be sure. Perhaps it is the wrong version. Or the link is wrong. Or it's 32 bit when it needs to be 64 bit. etc. Find the file and examine it. Basic debugging would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Can you guide me?
This is the output as i try to install it
`libevent-dev is already the newest version (2.1.8-stable-4build1).`